# Display a field only when dependee image field has more than three images

Tags: media

I have a content type "Product", and on its view node, I want to display a field(which is a select list), only when my other field, which is dependee for this field and is an image field, contains more than three images.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.

> Define dependencies between fields based on their states and values.
>
> Conditional Fields for Drupal 7 is an user interface to the new States
>   API, plus the ability to modify fields appearance and behavior on
>   certain conditions when viewing content.

[How to use ?](https://www.drupal.org/node/1704126)